# Angular UI-Router Resolve not preventing state change before AJAX Complete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angular-ui-router

I am in the process of building a new editorial website for my company with an Uncoupled CMS backend and Angular/Node/Express front end.

I have four different types of articles; each article has a flag (number) denoting what type of article it is. I'm using ng-switch to look at this flag and then display the proper view.

Unfortunately, the view template keeps rendering before my AJAX request is complete, resulting in a completely white page. I tried implementing the UI-Router Resolve functionality to fix this, and while I'm successfully completing the AJAX request, my article is still not being rendered and the template loads too quickly.

This is my controller:

```
    angular
     .module('glossy')
     .controller('PostController', PostController)

   PostController.$inject = [
     '$stateParams',
     'storePostService',
     'categoryFilterService',
     'categoryPostsService',
     'getPost'];

   function PostController($stateParams, storePostService, categoryFilterService, categoryPostsService, getPost){

     // Instantiate variables
     var vm = this;
     vm.postTitle = $stateParams.title;
     vm.categorySlug = $stateParams.category;
     vm.thisPost = getPost;
     vm.category = [];
     vm.related = [];

     getCategoryPosts();

     function getCategoryPosts(){
        return categoryPostsService.getCategoryPosts(vm.categorySlug)
          .then(function(data){
            vm.related = data;
            console.log(vm.related);
            return vm.related;
          });
      }
  }
```

This is the relevant part of my State Provider:

```
    angular
      .module('glossy.states', [])
      .config([
        '$stateProvider',
        '$urlRouterProvider',
        '$locationProvider',
        function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){
          $stateProvider
            .state('post', {
              url: '/:category/:title',
              views: {
                "": {
                  controller: 'PostController as posts',
                  resolve: {
                    getPost: ['$http', '$stateParams',
                      function($http, $stateParams) {
                        var slug = $stateParams.title;
                        return $http.get('/api/' + slug)
                          .then(function(response){
                            console.log(response.data);
                            return response.data;
                           });
                       }
                     ]
                  },
                  templateUrl: '/app/post/post.view.html'
                },
                "lead@post": {
                  templateUrl: '/app/post/lead.view.html'
                },
                "quick@post": {
                  templateUrl: '/app/post/quick.view.html'
                },
                "short@post": {
                  templateUrl: '/app/post/short.view.html'
                },
                "video@post": {
                  templateUrl: '/app/post/video.view.html'
                }
            }
         })
```

And this is the template that determines which type of article should be displayed:

```
    <div ng-switch="posts.thisPost.acf.post_type">

      <!-- Lead Article -->
      <div ng-switch-when="1">
        <div ui-view="lead" autoscroll="true"></div>
      </div>

      <!-- Quick Article -->
      <div ng-switch-when="2">
        <div ui-view="quick" autoscroll="true"></div>
      </div>

      <!-- Quick Short Article -->
      <div ng-switch-when="3">
        <div ui-view="short" autoscroll="true"></div>
      </div>

      <!-- Video Article -->
      <div ng-switch-when="4">
        <div ui-view="video" autoscroll="true"><div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Am I missing something here? I thought the point of Resolve was that the template wouldn't render until the AJAX Request was completed and I could use the data? If this is not the case, does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

I would try creating a service to hold your posts, and inject it into the getPost function as well as your controller. Then when get your AJAX response during the state resolution, in your .then function you can call `PostService.updatePost(response.data)`. 
And your `vm.thisPost = getPost` will become `vm.thisPost = PostService.currentPost`.